# Nodemailer send mail using gmail account showing response code 534-5.7.14

Tags: node.js, gmail, nodemailer

```
// create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport

transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true, 
    auth: {
        user: 'yourEmail', 
        pass: 'yourPassword' 
    }
});
```

> { [Error: Invalid login] code: 'EAUTH', response: '534-5.7.14
>   
>   Please log in via your web browser and\n534-5.7.14 then try
>   again.\n534-5.7.14 Learn more at n534 5.7.14
>   https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 77sm13524842wml.20 - g
>   smtp', responseCode: 534 }

Answer (score 3):

You may need to "[Allow Less Secure Apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)" in your Gmail account (it's all the way at the bottom). You also may need to "[Allow access to your Google account](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)".

Answer (score 0):

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    host: config.email_config.SMTP_HOST,
    port: config.email_config.SMTP_PORT,
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    },
    auth: {
        user: config.email_config.SMTP_AUTH_USER,
        pass: config.email_config.SMTP_AUTH_PASS
    }
}));

use like thiss....
```